# attach($user->id) isn't working and is rendering as null

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

I have a messaging system that allows users to message each other, reply to messages, and be notified when they are messaged. The problem I am having is `$conversation->participants()->attach($reciever->id);` returns null and doesn't seem to attach the conversations participants I `dd()` the value.

**InboxTest.php**

```
public function a_user_can_leave_a_reply_in_conversation()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling();

    $this->actingAs($user = factory('App\User')->create());

    $conversation = factory('App\Conversation')->create();

    $reciever = factory('App\User')->create();

    $conversation->participants()->attach($reciever->id);

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/api/message/'. $conversation->hashed_id . '/reply', ['body'=> 'A new message.'])
        ->assertStatus(201);

    $response->assertJsonFragment(['body' => 'A new message.']);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('messages', [
        'conversation_id' => $conversation->id,
        'sender_id' => $user->id,
        'body' => 'A new message.'
    ]);

    $this->assertDatabaseHas('conversation_participants',[
        'user_id' => $reciever->id
    ]);
}
```

This is leading too an error with the notifications system:

> Error: Call to a member function routeNotificationFor() on null

**InboxController.php**

```
public function reply($hashedId, Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    $conversation = Conversation::where('hashed_id', $hashedId)->first();

    $users = $conversation->recipients;

    $notifications = Notification::send($users, new MessageNotification(auth()->user()));

    $message = $conversation->messages()->create([
        'sender_id' => auth()->user()->id,
        'body' => $request->body,
    ]);

    return new MessageResource($message);
}
```

Here's my relationships:

**Conversations.php**

```
public function participants()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User' ,'conversation_participants','conversation_id','user_id')->withPivot(['status','is_sender']);
}
```

**User.php**

```
public function conversations()

{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Conversation','conversation_participants', 'user_id', 'conversation_id');
}
```

Is it possible that `withPivot()` in `participants()` relationship method is messing with things? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `recipients` relation in the conversation model.

But in the controller, you're trying to get the users using recipients relation, and sending the notification to those users.

InboxController.php

```
$users = $conversation->recipients;

$notifications = Notification::send($users, new 
      MessageNotification(auth()->user()));
```

What I can understand from your test function is that you've nowhere attached any user to the recipient method. You're attaching it with the participants relation.

InboxTest.php

```
$reciever = factory('App\User')->create();
$conversation->participants()->attach($reciever->id);
```

The way of attaching is perfectly fine as you've written.

Maybe there's something to do with the participants/recipients relation. Let me know in the comments if I got anything wrong.